# Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm getting this error when trying to open the connection in code as follows:

```
 string queryString = "Insert into Table;

        OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = Settings.Default.STIMConnectionString;
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString,connection);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My Appconfig is as follows:

```
 <add name="WindowsFormsApplicationTransducer.Properties.Settings.STIMConnection"
  connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data    Source=&quot;D:\Development\SS Observer II Decoder.mdb&quot;" />
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the OdbcConnection, I think you need to include the "Driver" information in your connection string.

Answer (score 3):

`Data Source` is not a valid connection string property. ODBC originally used a data source name, or `DSN=dsnname`, where the DSN was configured separately on the system. However you can alternatively specify the driver and driver-specific parameters, which in the case of the Microsoft Access driver is at the minimum the file name: `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\Development\SS Observer II Decoder.mdb`.

Comment: This was exactly what i needed. I didn't see your answer until after i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

See http://connectionstrings.com/  to see what you need to have.